# How does one Move Commits from the Head of a Branch into a New Branch and not have them be Discarded when Merged back in?

Tags: git

I've made some commits on a branch I was not supposed to!

**Sprint 1 Branch**

- Commit #4
- Commit #3
- Commit #2
- Commit #1

I want to move **Commits #2 - #4** into a **Hot Fix Branch** so that they can be merged back into the **Sprint 1 Branch** at a later date.  It is important that whatever I do on the Sprint 1 Branch to get rid of these commits temporarily won't take precedence over these commits when I merge them back in (e.g. reverting them after creating a hotfix branch for them).  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, in git, there are many possibilities to achieve something. So, let's say you have 4 commits on branch `sprint` and you want to *move* the last commits to a branch fix. To simulate your problem, I created the `sprint` branch as follows:

```
git checkout -b sprint
touch c1 c2 c3 c4
git add c1
git commit -m "commit 1"
git add c2
git commit -m "commit 2"
git add c3
git commit -m "commit 3"
git add c4
git commit -m "commit 4"
git push origin sprint
```

Now, instead of moving commits, we just create the `fix` branch from the `head` of the `sprint` branch:

```
git checkout -b fix
git push origin fix
```

Now, we reset the `sprint` branch to the first commit.

```
git checkout sprint
git log --oneline # copy the hash of the first commit, say f58f8d8
git reset --hard f58f8d8
git push -f origin sprint # -f (force option) is needed because of the hard reset
```

So, the `fix` branch has now all the commits, and the `sprint` branch only has the first commit, which, I understand, is what you needed.

**EDIT**: you need `RW+` permissions to use the `-f` or `--force` option (see comments below).

Comment: @MattArnold There was a typo in the git reset --hard. Corrected now.

Comment: I had just tried a hard reset and was wondering why in Source Tree it was claiming I had commits to pull instead of push!  I believe the `-f` option is what I was missing.  However, I'm now unable to push as I'm getting a "remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/sprint".  Would this be another issue or related?

Comment: @MattArnold If you have commits to pull, that means your remote's head is farther than your local head. So, first you pull, then you push. If it doesn't work, we should move this to the chat in order to not comment on things not directly related to the question (not sure if that's possible though lol).

Comment: Let's move this into chat (I see no option for it yet); I pulled those commits and they were all the ones I just reset!

Comment: That's because you didn't push the sprint branch to the remote. If you follow the codes from the answer:
git checkout sprint
git reset --hard <hash first commit>
git push -f origin sprint
it should work.

Comment: I'm still having no luck with the `push -f origin sprint` command.  This is the complete error (with sensitive data changed).
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: FATAL: + refs/heads/sprint SomeRepository id_rsa-mattarnold DENIED by fallthru
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/sprint
To ssh://SomeGitServer/SomeRepository
 ! [remote rejected]   sprint -> sprint (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@SomeGitServer/SomeRepository'

Comment: Have you been able to push the fix branch? Do you maintain the repo on the server? It seems you have sone configuration issues on the server side.

Comment: I was able to push the fix branch.  Unfortunately I don't maintain the repo on the server so cannot create a fresh repo to test this with.

Comment: It is most likely due to the -f option. It seems you have no RW+ rights for ref changes. Are you using gitolite?

Comment: Then you should ask for RW+ permissions to the maintainer. You could also just remove the sprint branch and create a new sprint branch from the first commit. That way, you don't need the -f command. Can you remove the sprint branch on the server side?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, we are not using Gitolite.  No one in the team has done a `push` using the `-f` flag before - does this require an elevated permission above a normal `push`?

Comment: Good thinking with the remote branch deletion and re-pushing as a fresh one - that will work for me.

Comment: Do you need me to edit the question to show how to do that?

Comment: Well there is something strange going on when I try to delete a remote branch.  I get this but then it deletes!
remote: FATAL: + refs/heads/hotfix/TestBranchToDelete SomeRepository id_rsa-mattarnold DENIED by fallthru        
remote: error: hook declined to update refs/heads/hotfix/TestBranchToDelete        
To ssh://SomeGitServer/SomeRepository
 ! [remote rejected]   hotfix/TestBranchToDelete (hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@SomeGitServer/SomeRepository'

Comment: Same problem as before. You don't have RW+ permissions. You could forget about sprint and make a new branch sprint1. Or ask the maintainer to delete the sprint branch.

Comment: Alright, I think I need to speak to the maintainers or our repository in that case.  Thanks for helping me get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Just to confirm, you were correct; now that I have RW+ permissions, `push -f` works.  I recommend adding that to the answer for others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197608/discussion-between-mfnx-and-matt-arnold).

Answer (score -2):

Use [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) for that case.
It rebases commits onto another branch.

Comment: How would I use it in this situation?  I thought Rebase was just for squashing commits together.

Comment: But it does not remove the commits from the sprint branch.

Comment: You're right. I apologize. A `git checkout -d hotfix` and `git reset` is still needed. Rebase is unnecessary.